# Multithreading in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe

This is my code below which is calculating some addition for each value & in loop printing it. If I want to implement **multithreading** here to run all the value calculation & get the result at end (in a dataframe preferably)

```
id_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6......100]
def my_func(id):
    id=id+10
df = pd.DataFrame()
for id in id_list:
    myresult = my_func(id)
    sub_df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": id,"Result": myresult}]
    df = df.append(sub_df)
print(df)
```

Comment: Here's answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954075/how-to-multi-thread-with-for-loop

Comment: Python has no real multithreading (keyword `GIL`). If `my_func` is heavy on the CPU then there's not much you can do, unless you find a library which does what you want in C code and also takes care of multithreading. If `my_func` is not heavy on the CPU but I/O bound, like fetch data from a database, then you should look into Python's `asyncio` features (or it's `threading` features). Multithreading won't help with CPU heavy tasks.

Comment: @DanielF It's opposite to what you state

Comment: There is an paranthesis error on this line. `sub_df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": id,"Result": myresult}]` and `df = df.append(sub_df)` also weird.  I think df.append is enough.

Comment: Also this answered my question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792171/multithreading-in-python-within-a-for-loop

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov You only can speed up CPU-bound problems by adding more cores to it, which the GIL won't allow you to do if you stay in Python (at least without the `multithreading` module). On the other hand, you can speed up multiple I/O-bound operations by performing other tasks while waiting for the operation to yield a result.